# GeoServer Tile Cache Misses

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geowebcache

#### Issue

I am getting a lot (~90%) tile cache misses with the error.
"request does not align to grid(s) 'EPSG:4326'"

The native SRS here is EPSG:7845, however the tile cache is set to use the default EPSG:4326, and does cache some tiles.

I have set the SRS bounds using 'Compute from SRS bounds' (from here: [GeoWebCache Miss: request does not align to grid(s) 'EPSG27700'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221306/geowebcache-miss-request-does-not-align-to-grids-epsg27700)) however still no dice.

I am a bit at a loss why it's hitting a small fraction of the requests, but not others. Apologies for the wall of text!

#### Work so far:

I have tried to meet all of the cache requirements here (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html)

> WMS Direct integration is enabled (you can set this on the Caching defaults page)

[image]

> tiled=true is included in the request
>
> The request only references a single layer

Yep! See below for full incoming request.

> Caching is enabled for that layer

[image]

> The image requested is of the same height and width as the size saved in the layer configuration

[image]
Yep! And see incoming request below.

> The requested CRS matches one of the available tile layer gridsets

Yep. EPSG:4326, the default, is kept as a cache. EPSG:4326 in the request image below.

> The image requested lines up with the existing grid bounds

[image]
Yep. Used 'compute from SRS', so it's a massive box.

> A parameter is included for which there is a corresponding Parameter Filter

I'm actually not sure what this one means...

I have a copy of the incoming request from leafletjs to address some of the above.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bounds of your request almost certainly don't align with the grid (138.2187, -33.1375) doesn't look like an even division of a lat/lon grid which I would expect to fall on numbers of degrees for a large number of zoom levels.

The simple solution is that if you want tiles then you should use a tiled map service like WMTS or TMS and take the guess work out of the situation.

Comment: Thanks @ian-turton for the guidance! I am looking into this now and will update. Unfortunately I'm working with a pile of libraries on libraries here. Not sure if I can find an basic-auth WMTS plugin for leafletjs! WMTS does appear to be a trivial solution to sort out the caching issue.